# Mono udpClient() unable to send - bad checksum

Tags: c#, mono, udpclient

I have a simple UDP application written in C#, that is required to run under mono in Linux. It works fine on my personal PC (windows 10), but the checksum is apparently bad on the Linux machine.

I have tried to disable the checksum, but that just makes it not send at all.

```
udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.NoChecksum, true);
```

The reason I know the checksum is bad, is because tcpdump shows me:

```
192.168.88.98.5059 > 192.168.88.37.5059: [bad udp cksum 0x3354 -> 0x56e7!] UDP, length 354
```

There is quite a lot of working code other than this, like TcpListener etc, this is the part that does NOT work:

```
...
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
udpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
// udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.NoChecksum, true);
udpClient.Client.Bind(IpEndPoint);
udpClient.Send(rtnMessage, rtnMessage.Length, RemoteIpEndPoint);
```

Also, with either of these options, checksum or not I don't get the UDP message on the other side.

Comment: Some more testing show that it must be the actual NIC producing the wrong checksum: `echo "Hello World" | nc -w1 -u 192.168.1.1 5050` also produces: ` [bad udp cksum 0x31fc -> 0x6653!]`

Comment: Its working now... seems to have been a NIC setting. `sudo ethtool -K eth0 rx on tx off`. Did the trick, and it working now. So in the end it was not a programming issue... but interestingly, it was not possible to set the socket option to disable the checksum.... this threw an error.